# How to parse just part of JSON with Klaxon?

Tags: json, kotlin, klaxon

I'm trying to parse some JSON to kotlin objects. The JSON looks like:

```
{
    data: [
        { "name": "aaa", "age": 11 },
        { "name": "bbb", "age": 22 },
    ],
    otherdata : "don't need"
}
```

I just need to `data` part of the entire JSON, and parse each item to a `User` object:

```
data class User(name:String, age:Int)
```

But I can't find an easy way to do it.

Comment: Not enough information, please provide the source code and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you can achieve this

```
import com.beust.klaxon.Klaxon
import java.io.StringReader

val json = """
    {
        "data": [
            { "name": "aaa", "age": 11 },
            { "name": "bbb", "age": 22 },
        ],
        "otherdata" : "not needed"
    }
""".trimIndent()

data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val klaxon = Klaxon()
    val parsed = klaxon.parseJsonObject(StringReader(json))
    val dataArray = parsed.array<Any>("data")
    val users = dataArray?.let { klaxon.parseFromJsonArray<User>(it) }
    println(users)
}
```

This will work as long as you can fit the whole json string in memory. Otherwise you may want to look into the streaming API: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon#streaming-api